# Javascript method failing to complete

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript method that is working on all browsers except google chrome, in order for me to get it to work in google chrome I have to add the uncommented alert. Any ideas how to make sure this completes without using an alert message:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#EnrolAndEnter").click(function (event) {

        var postData = {
            'courseID': '@Model.Course.CourseID'
        };

        $.post('/Course/EnrolUser/', postData, function (data) {
            document.getElementById("EnrolAndEnter").innerHTML = "<i class=\"icon-external-link\"></i>Enter";
        });

        //alert("SUCCESS");

    });
});
```

I then updated my method to this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#EnrolAndEnter").click(function (event) {

        var postData = {
            'courseID': '@Model.Course.CourseID'
        };

        alert("MSG1");
        $.when($.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: '/Course/EnrolUser/',                 
            data: postData
        }))
        .done(function () {
            document.getElementById("EnrolAndEnter").innerHTML = "<i class=\"icon-external-link\"></i>Enter";

        });
        alert("MSG2");
    });
});
```

Again this is only ever calling the EnrolUser method on the controller when the alert is included. If the alert is not included it does nothing and just redirects to the HREF assigned route which should be preempted by the registration

Comment: What exactly is working/not working? Are you getting any errors? You've not given us much to go on. What is your expected output?

Comment: There is no error it just skips the post statement without the alert message being included, I have also updated my answer to show using a When.Done method that is being executed out of order. The alert second alert is fired before the When statement is called

Comment: using callbacks, you cannot say in which order JavaScript executes: the `$.when` is read by the engine and whenever the function `when` decides, the callback is executed. In the meantime the next line `alert` is executed.

Have you tried using `debugger;` and stepping through the code?

Comment: yes the debug was as described in my post

Comment: What kind of element is `#EnrolAndEnter`? Is it part of a form? What do you mean by 'redirects to the HREF assigned route'? Does the browser change the page?

Answer (score 0):

Try `console.log('Success');`

This writes to the JavaScript console (press F12 and go to "Console").

JavaScript execution halts until an alert returns a value so it might be failing because the alert is fired before the POST execution has finished.

Comment: Does not fire even without the alert and or with the console.log message

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry I misunderstood your question

Comment: @Jay -- has it printed success on console ??

Answer (score 0):

HREF on the link was being fired and completed before the Javascript onclick event had time to complete was a timing issue